# Parsing colon-delimited text from a file

Tags: python, discord.py

```
n = 0

@bot.command()
async def check(ctx):

    global n

    ACC = open('test.data', 'r')
    # In test.data's detail:
    # 1st:2nd
    # 3rd:4th

    ACC1 = ACC.readlines()
    ACC2=str(ACC1).split()
    ACC3=str(ACC2).split(':')

    ctx.send('{}'.format(ACC3[n]))

    n+=1
```

I want to output like:

```
player: !check
bot : 1st
player: !check
bot : 2nd
player: !check
bot : 3rd
```

It outputs too many list.

I was temporarily happy to implement the string without error, but it was totally different from my expectations when I executed the code. What should I do? I don't think there was any helpful answer either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ACC.readlines()` already returns a list of lines in the file. So all we need to do is split `:` on each line and flatten the list.

```
checks = []
with open('test.data', 'r') as ACC:
    for line in ACC.readlines():
        checks.extend(line.split(':'))

ctx.send(checks[n])
```